# Getting Soap Error SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load..... failed to load external entity

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

```
    //put those data in an array to make the xml below
    $xml = '<order>';
    $xml.=             '<details>';
    $xml.=                '<id>'.$order_number.'</id>';
    $xml.=                '<restaurant>_Generic</restaurant>';
    $xml.=                '<datePlaced>'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'</datePlaced>';
    $xml.=                '<deliveryDate>'.$delivery.'</deliveryDate>';    
    $xml.=                '<totalPrice>'.$total.'</totalPrice>';
    $xml.=                '<totalTax>'.$total_tax.'</totalTax>';
    $xml.=                '<totalDiscount>'.$total_discount.'</totalDiscount>';
    $xml.=                '<deliveryFee>'.$total_shipping.'</deliveryFee>';
    $xml.=                '<deliveryFeeTaxable>true</deliveryFeeTaxable>';
    $xml.=                '<tip>0.00</tip>';
    $xml.=                '<orderType>'.$shipping_method.'</orderType>';
    $xml.=                '<orderStatus>ProcessedOffline</orderStatus>';
    $xml.=                '<orderComment>'.$order_comments.'</orderComment>';
    $xml.=             '</details>';
    $xml.=             '<customer>';
    $xml.=                '<billingAddress>';
    $xml.=                   '<firstName>'.$first_name.'</firstName>';
    $xml.=                   '<lastName>'.$last_name.'</lastName>';
    $xml.=                   '<companyName>'.$company.'</companyName>';
    $xml.=                   '<phoneNumber>'.$phone.'</phoneNumber>';
    $xml.=                   '<address1>'.$address_1.'</address1>';
    $xml.=                   '<address1>'.$address_2.'</address1>';
    $xml.=                   '<city>'.$city.'</city>';
    $xml.=                   '<state>'.$state.'</state>';
    $xml.=                   '<zipCode>'.$postcode.'</zipCode>';
    $xml.=                '</billingAddress>';
    $xml.=                '<deliveryAddress>';
    $xml.=                   '<firstName>'.$meta['_shipping_first_name'][0].'</firstName>';
    $xml.=                   '<lastName>'.$meta['_shipping_last_name'][0].'</lastName>';
    $xml.=                   '<companyName>'.$meta['_shipping_company'][0].'</companyName>';
    $xml.=                   '<phoneNumber>'.$phone.'</phoneNumber>';
    $xml.=                   '<address1>'.$meta['_shipping_address_1'][0].'</address1>';
    $xml.=                   '<address2 />';
    $xml.=                   '<city>'. $meta['_shipping_city'][0].'</city>';
    $xml.=                   '<state>'. $meta['_shipping_state'][0].'</state>';
    $xml.=                   '<zipCode>'. $meta['_shipping_postcode'][0].'</zipCode>';
    $xml.=                '</deliveryAddress>';
    $xml.=                '<carInformation />';
    $xml.=                '<pickupInformation />';
    $xml.=             '</customer>';
    $xml.=             '<items>';








                 foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

                          $product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );

                   $xml.= '<item>';
    $xml.=  '<plu></plu>';
    $xml.=       '<title>'.$item['name'].'</title>';
    $xml.=       '<itemPrice>'.$item['item_meta']['_line_total'][0].'</itemPrice>';
    $xml.=       '<qty>'.$item['qty'].'</qty>';
    $xml.=       '<recipient />';
    $xml.=       '<itemComment />';

                                             $xml.= '<options>';
                                                    $xml.=  '<option>';
                $xml.=     '<plu></plu>';
                $xml.=     '<title>'.$item['size'].'</title>';
                $xml.=     '<value>'.$item['brand'].'</value>';
                $xml.=     '<price></price>';
                $xml.=  '</option>';

                                                     $xml.= '</options>';
                     $xml.='</item>';


     }



          $xml.= '</items>';





    $xml.=             '<payment>';
    $xml.=                '<type>CreditCard</type>';
    $xml.=                '<cardInformation>';
    $xml.=                   '<nameOnCard>'.$a.'</nameOnCard>';
    $xml.=                   '<cardType />';
    //$xml.=                     '<cardNumber>'.$a.'</cardNumber>';
    $xml.=                   '<cardNumber>'.$a.'</cardNumber>';
    $xml.=                   '<expMonth>'.$a.'</expMonth>';
    $xml.=                   '<expYear>'.$a.'</expYear>';
    $xml.=                   '<gateway>OfflineProcessing</gateway>';
    $xml.=                   '<transactionType />';
    $xml.=                   '<transactionID />';
    $xml.=                '</cardInformation>';
    $xml.=             '</payment>';
    $xml.=          '</order>';
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0");
    ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 100);



            $clienturl = 'http://69.73.228.16:8008/weborder/OnlineOrderXmlProcessor.asmx?WSDL'; // live site



    $client = new SoapClient($clienturl); 


//  print_r($xml);

    $params = array();
    $params["strDocType"] = 'OrderImport';
    $params["strXml"] = $xml;
    $result = $client->ProcessXML($params);
```

It's not working. But same code used for dev server with different URL.
In live server same configuration but showing error.

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://69.73.228.16:8008/weborder/OnlineOrderXmlProcessor.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "http://69.73.228.16:8008/weborder/OnlineOrderXmlProcessor.asmx?WSDL"

Comment: In your wsdl, You must be importing some external schema, which won't be accesible on your live server. Check first few lines of wsdl, you will find some import statements. Check those links in live server. Are you able to access them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I got solution.

After disabling CSF Firewall My code is working.

You can check it via curl.

open SSH and type :

```
curl  -A ''  -4 http://google.com
```

you'll get reply.
Now check it by your WDSL URL.
If you got error,, You should disable the firewall.