# Mac PHP Soap Error after Update to Sierra

Tags: php, soap

Recently i've updated my Mac with Sierra 10.12.

The install have reset my apache config and it seems it update the php version, luckily it preserve the old configuration files so i've restored my old apache settings,

For php is different.
In one of my projects soap extension stopped working, and give me this error message.

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'SOMERESOURCEURL' : failed to load external entity "SOMESOURCEURL".

i'm sure that before the upgrade to sierra:

- I haven't modified anything in my app source code
- I use the standard php configuration  (i'm not using custom php.ini files i've checked with a `<?php phpinfo() ?>` )
- SOMERESOURCEURL is online and it response fine with a curl interrogation

> curl  -A ''  -4 https://SOMERESOURCEURL

- In my Server the application Soap Works fine.

And i'm sure that after upgrading to sierra:

- The same points before upgrading are also true after the update
- I've restored my old apache configurations correctly and php module is enabled.

I've also tried to create a php.ini with all the configuration for enabling soap correctly, but it give me the same error.

> ENABLED  extension=php_openssl.dll, extension=php_curl.dll,
>   extension=php_soap.dll, extension=php_xmlrpc.dll

So i've restored the old configurations.

Some of you had a same / similar problem?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Soap Error SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load..... failed to load external entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862850/getting-soap-error-soap-error-parsing-wsdl-couldnt-load-failed-to-load-e)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, i've checked with curl the server WSDL and it response fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution,

i've find out that php 5.6 by default enable ssl certification so i pass this:

```
 "stream_context" => stream_context_create(
                    array(
                        'ssl' => array(
                            'verify_peer'       => false,
                            'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                        )
                    )
                )
```

For disable it and now works fine.